# Подсчет символов в текстовых полях

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Требуется подсчитать количество символов в текстовых полях `input` и `textarea` и если текст больше допустимого, тогда фон поля подсветить красным или желтым цветом (желательно чтобы текст который добавляется в текстовое поле не обрезался, если он большой а просто подсвечивался красным цветом).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Недавно скачал подобный скрипт, думаю тебе подойдет и в зжатом виде занимает меньше 1 Кб. Вот [ссылка](https://github.com/helloilya/jquery-countchar) на этот скрипт.
Нужно подключить сам скрипт и добавить на страницу такой код:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('[data-countchar]').countChar({
        text: 'Characters:'
    });
});
```

Html:

```
<input type="text" name="name" data-countchar="[a-z]+" placeholder="текст">
<input type="text" name="age" data-countchar="[\d]+" placeholder="цифры">  
<textarea name="desc" data-countchar="" data-countchar-limit="15" placeholder="Максимум 15 символов"></textarea>
```

`data-countchar-limit="15"` = максимальное количество символов (15).

`data-countchar="[a-z]+"` = какие именно символы подсчитывать (a-z).

Answer (score 0):

Вместо `change` можете использовать `input`, если нужна мгновенная реакция. Сейчас скрипт работает, когда элемент становится неактивным.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var input = $('.input');
  var textarea = $('.textarea');
  
  $(document).on('change','.input',function(){
    if(input.val().length < 6) { // если < 6 символов
      input.css('background','#FF0000');
      return false;
    }
    else {
      input.css('background','#FFFFFF');
      return true;
    }
  });
  
  $(document).on('change','.textarea',function(){
    if(textarea.val().length < 6) { // если < 6 символов
      textarea.css('background','#FF0000');
      return false;
    }
    else {
      textarea.css('background','#FFFFFF');
      return true;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="input" type="text" name="text"><br /><br />
<textarea class="textarea" name="textarea"></textarea>
```

Comment: А как сделать чтобы этот скрипт подсчитывал для нескольких полей отдельно? Т.е. у каждого поля свой счетчик, а не один на все поля